# web scraping a dynamic table with authentication

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am new to python and web scraping and i'm trying to scrape a website that uses JavaScript. I have managed to automate the log in sequence via Selenium, however when I try to send the API call to get the data, I am not able to get anything. I'm assuming it's because the API call requires some sort of authentication. How can I get past this?

Here's my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json


username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'

url = 'https://www.example.com/login'

#log in
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login_button"]').click()

# go to User Lines
driver.get('http://www.example.com/lines')

time.sleep(5)

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

subs = json.loads(response.text)

print(subs)
```

Comment: correct, Using Selenium and then requests are not the same session. You'd need to access the data from the same selenium session. So the requests doesnt recognize the login. Mind share what site you're accessing?

Comment: Once you login, why can't you pass the html from selenium to bs4 for parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Every time an HTTP request is made some metadata is included. This is all the header data and cookies and maybe some other session data. It has to be sent every time because that's the only way to maintain a 'session'

If you login in Selenium, the browser is managing your session there. Making a request with the python requests library has nothing to do with Selenium, and most likely the authentication that you're missing is what is provided by logging in in Selenium.

So you have a few options:

**1. Make the API call using Selenium** After logging in just get() the API URL and the page source should be the data within a  tag.

**2. Log in using the requests library** Instead of using Selenium, you can exclusively use requests. This can be tedious; you'll have to inspect the network calls using the devtools and piece together what you would need to replicate using requests to simulate the same login that happens on the browser. You would also need to use a persistent session using **requests.Session()** to create a session instance. You can use this object to make the requests instead of the requests library directly. But once you do, you can just make the API request as you were. This method has the fastest runtime too since you're not rendering a whole browser and running the javascript within that, and making all the network requests therein.

**3. Pass the session data from Selenium to your requests' session instance** I haven't tried doing this, but since session data is just passed along in the headers and are just strings, you can probably find a way to get the cookies from Selenium and add them to your session requests instance to make your API call without selenium.

Comment: Don't forget #4. use fetch from the browser side. This is how the website is getting it, it sounds like.

Comment: @pguardiario yes but he's running a web scraper in python. Do you mean he can use fetch from within Selenium?

Comment: Yes, with driver.execute_async_script